# Where to start monitoring queue in ASP.NET Core hosted service

Tags: asp.net-core-webapi, asp.net-core-hosted-services

I'm following [this example for a queued hosted service](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/host/hosted-services?view=aspnetcore-3.1&tabs=visual-studio) to add this to an ASP.NET Core application, and it's not clear to me where `StartMonitorLoop` should be called. I ended up modifying it to be `EnsureMonitorLoop`, added a check so that it's the call to `Task.Run` is only made once, added a `MonitorLoop` parameter to constructor for my API controller, and called `EnsureMonitorLoop` from there. It smells kind of funny to me that the API controller constructor should be kicking off monitoring the queue. The example [`Program.cs`](https://github.com/aspnet/AspNetCore.Docs/blob/master/aspnetcore/fundamentals/host/hosted-services/samples/3.x/BackgroundTasksSample/Program.cs) seems is very different from the one generated for me by Visual Studio. Mine uses the `WebHost.CreateDefaultBuilder(args).UseStartup<Startup>` approach. That is where they call `StartMonitorLoop`.

Where is the correct place to call `StartMonitorLoop`, and why? Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The docs aren't super clear here, but `MonitorLoop` is not actually part of this. It's an example service for use in a console app, simply to demonstrate how the queued background worker works. You can take some inspiration from this class for your app, but the concept of `StartMonitorLoop` doesn't apply to ASP.NET Core at all.

Just to be a bit more clear: in actual practice you would inject `IBackgroundTaskQueue` into a controller class, for example, and then add some task to that, just like `MonitorLoop` does (without all the key input jazz). You wouldn't actually have `MonitorLoop` or anything like it though.